# In what order are the points on the hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with $\angle ACB=90^\circ$. Let $CM=m_c$ be the median and $CH=h_c$ be the altitude through $C$.

I want to understand how I should approach problems with similar configuration. In what order are the points on $AB$? That depends on the angles of the triangle, doesn't it? I want to see it myself that if $\measuredangle BAC>\measuredangle ABC$, then $AH<AM$. So if we suppose that $CH'\perp AB, AH'>AM$, how to show this is not possible? I have not studied trigonometry!!

Comment: It's perfectly clear from the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard notation $$AM=m_c=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}.$$
Also, $$AC^2=AH\cdot AB,$$ which gives $$AH=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Thus, $$AM-AH=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}-\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I really appreciate it. How should I end the solution? Can we see what $AH-AM$ is, not $AM-AH$?

Comment: It depends on $a-b$. If $a>b$ so $AM>AH$ and $H$ is placed between $A$ and $M$. The case $a<b$ is the similar.

Comment: Can we write the result as $AM-AH=\dfrac{(a-b)(a+b)}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$? Now I think we can see it easily.